# How to show users Online and with Photos filter on views

Tags: views

want a view that will have this functionality:

https://www.thaifriendly.com/browse.php

There is a radio box to see users that are:

1. Online
2. With Photos

I have played with views but can't find a way to make it work, the current_user field works, but it only displays the user that is logged in at the moment, not ALL logged in users

There is not current_user filed in sort either.

Thanks,
Bruno

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking how to implement a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or the link to the site where the functionality/layout has been seen is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter by "Last Access" and set it to show Last access is less than or Equal to -2 Minutes
;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the [User Stats](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_stats) module

> Provides commonly requested user statistics for themers, IP address tracking and **Views** integration.
>
> Statistics are:
>
> 1. days registered;
> 2. join date;
> 3. days since
>      last login;
> 4. days since last post;
> 5. post count;
> 6. login count;
> 7. **user online/offline;**
> 8. IP
>      address;